# TA880GB+ motherboard with Realtek ALC892 = No Sound

Tags: sound, hdmi, realtek

My HTPC has the Biostar TA880GB+ Motherboard installed. I'm using the HDMI port and for the life of me I can not get sound to work at all.. I am using the onboard Realtek ALC892 6-Channel Blu-ray Audio. If anyone has a solution please help! I'd love to get off windows 7 and keep using Ubuntu 12.10

Thanks in advance!